# How can I use Filter Views along with drop-down list filters?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm currently using a combination of `=query()` function and a drop-down list to create a report. However, this report will be shared with many users and I'd like to create Filter Views for each user so that they can have their own instance and not filter over each other.

The problem I'm running into is I'm unable to turn my drop-down list into a Filter View and when a user selects something within the drop-down cell, they end up filtering the entire sheet based on the query function.

How can I create separate instances for our users so they aren't filtering over each other when my filtering is done through drop-down lists?

Comment: pls share a copy/dummy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can't be done how you imagine it. if a dropdown cell controls directly the query you can't create (pre-define) filter over it, because a filter like that would directly override the query itself by each user who will touch that filter resulting in destroyed filter view of the previous user.

the only option here is to prompt each an every user to create own filtered view on his side. this way the control is moved to each individual user and all acts **independently** to the rest of the users wich filter stuff for their needs. (sadly in this scenario, whole drop-down is pointless)

### **in other words... instead of this:**

[image]

## **you (every user) will need to do this:**

[image]

## **using this type of filter:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @player0. I've pretty much just went with creating multiple tabs for our users, there is a heavier preference on having the drop-down list as filter.  Otherwise, I would just have the entire data table available for viewing and set filter views for everyone.